# multi-friend selector does not work in https (secure browsing enabled)

Tags: facebook, https, multi-friend-selector

We are using facebook iframe app in https mode, from our app we need to send an invitation to multiple friends using multi-friend selector.
But when we click on Select Friends button, it is showing blank popup. It works fine for http (non secure browsing).

```
"<fb:serverfbml><script type=\"text/fbml\">" +
"<fb:fbml>" +
"<fb:request-form action=\"" + (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection ? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Callback"].Replace("http://", "https://") : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Callback"]) + "pagename.aspx?dbskip=true&fb_sig_user=" + fbuserid + "\"" +
"method=\"POST\"" +
"invite=\"true\"" +
"type=\"My App \"" +
"content=\"" + "my content" +
"<fb:req-choice url='" + "my choice"+ "'" +
"label='" + " my text "+ "'/>" +
"\">" +
"<fb:multi-friend-selector bypass=\"cancel\" email_invite=\"false\" max=\"35\" cols=\"5\" actiontext=\"Select friends to send invitation\" rows=\"3\"/>" +
"</fb:request-form></fb:fbml></script></fb:serverfbml>";
```

Thank in advance......

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you shouldn't use legacy FBML now. It is deprecated.

Comment: True, but it's not unsupported until after January, it should work

Comment: Thanks a lot Xiaoxi!

Can u please suggest us the best/simple way to implement multi-friend selector without using of FBML?

Thanks in advance.........

Comment: True, but it doesn't answer the question.